# BigInteger testing for prime loop WITHOUT isProbablePrime

Tags: java, eclipse, primes, biginteger

In an assignment for class we have to make a loop to test for prime with a big integer WITHOUT using isProbablePrime. This is what we have.

```
package src.bigInteger;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BigIntegerTester {
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger();

    public boolean isPrime(BigInteger number) {
        boolean result = true;
        if (number == 2) result = true;
        for (int i = 3; i <= number/2; i += 2) {
            if (number % i == 0) {result = false;}
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

How can we get this to work?

Comment: what is not working?  Does your code compile?

Comment: maybe `number.intValue() == `

Comment: @ScaryWombat autoboxing and unboxing is done with helper classes. No need to call intValue()

Comment: @DogukanZengin No, it doesn't

Comment: @Zachary Sorry mistaken with the Integer class

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot compare `BigInteger` using `==`. You should be comparing it against another `BigInteger` Object using `BigInteger.compareTo(BigInteger val)`. If you want to compare as an `int`, for example, you can use `BigInteger.intValue()`.
2. You cannot perform arithmetic operations on the `BigInteger` Object (`number/2`). `BigInteger` has methods that will perform these operations, `BigInteger.divide(BigInteger val)`
3. Once you have established the number is a Prime, you should either `break` or `return` from the for loop.
4. There isn't much point using `BigInteger` as this algorithm will not
   scale well. If you were to use a number too large to be held in an `int`, the computation time would be **incredibly** long.
5. The second line of the `isPrime(...)` method, (`if (number == 2) result = true;`), is redundant.
6. Your algorithm incorrectly classifies any power of 2, where the power is greater than 1, as prime.
7. 1 is not prime.

There are many resources available that provide more efficient techniques to calculating whether an integer is a prime; you may want to give some of these a read.

Comment: I may be dense, but I don't get point 6. How or where does it do that?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis The modulus of the number and i is used to determine if i is a factor of the number. i starts at 3 and is incremented by 2, meaning the algorithm only checks whether any odd numbers (up to half the number) are factors of the number. As such, 4, 8, 16, and so forth (all non-primes where all prime factors are 2) are classified as prime.